# Android | Kotlin | I have this problem. GeoJson parsing Mapbox map Exception

Tags: exception, geojson, mapbox-android

FATAL EXCEPTION: GEOJSON_PARSER
Process: com.example.test, PID: 10995
com.mapbox.maps.MapboxConcurrentGeometryModificationException: While applying FeatureCollection to geojson source with id="line" some collection was mutated which is not allowed as data parsing happens on another thread.
Please make sure all collections passed via `geometry`, `feature`, `featureCollection` methods are immutable.
Easiest way to achieve this is either always pass the fresh copy or use https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.
at com.mapbox.maps.extension.style.sources.generated.GeoJsonSource.toPropertyValue(GeoJsonSource.kt:337)
at com.mapbox.maps.extension.style.sources.generated.GeoJsonSource.applyGeoJsonData$lambda-11$lambda-10(GeoJsonSource.kt:353)
at com.mapbox.maps.extension.style.sources.generated.GeoJsonSource.$r8$lambda$_9l_l-ZA5tTLYApH7jbY6OB3HUI(Unknown Source:0)
at com.mapbox.maps.extension.style.sources.generated.GeoJsonSource$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:4)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

Comment: Hey Kawan! Any updates on this? Were you able to fix it? If so, how?